# My ggplot barplot is showing a blank variable/I'm getting an error when trying to recode the bar title

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's my reprex of my code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(forcats)
religion2 <- rename(religion, comfort_practice_religion_umprompted = How.comfortable.would.you.be.seeing.someone.who.practices.a.different.religion.from.you..Ask.you.about.your.religion..unprompted..in.conversation)
#> Error in rename(religion, comfort_practice_religion_umprompted = How.comfortable.would.you.be.seeing.someone.who.practices.a.different.religion.from.you..Ask.you.about.your.religion..unprompted..in.conversation): object 'religion' not found
ggplot(data=religion2) + geom_bar(aes(x=comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, fill=comfort_practice_religion_umprompted))
#> Error in ggplot(data = religion2): object 'religion2' not found

religion <- mutate(religion2, comfort_practice_religion_umprompted = fct_recode(comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, "No response" = ""))
#> Error in mutate(religion2, comfort_practice_religion_umprompted = fct_recode(comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, : object 'religion2' not found

religion <- mutate(religion2, comfort_practice_religion_umprompted = fct_relevel(comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, "Extremely comfortable","Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "No response"))
#> Error in mutate(religion2, comfort_practice_religion_umprompted = fct_relevel(comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, : object 'religion2' not found

ggplot(religion) + geom_bar(aes(x=comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, fill=comfort_practice_religion_umprompted, y=..count../sum(..count..)))
#> Error in ggplot(religion): object 'religion' not found
dput(religion2)                                
#> Error in dput(religion2): object 'religion2' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here's my dput output

```
c("Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not at all comfortable", "", "Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not so comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not so comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Not so comfortable", "", "Very comfortable", 
"Not so comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Very comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Not so comfortable", 
"Extremely comfortable", "Not so comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Very comfortable", 
"Somewhat comfortably", "Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably", 
"Not at all comfortable", "Extremely comfortable", "Not at all comfortable", 
"Very comfortable", "Somewhat comfortably")
```

It keeps showing up as a blank variable/title like this [image: Graph] even after I thought I recoded the "no response" column so that it would say no response instead of being blank. I'm wondering how to fix it so that "no response" is the title of that empty bar (the pink one).

My data looks like this, [image: Data] I'm hoping it's not crucial that you have the copy of my data but let me know if I need to copy it a different way/include it in a different way. The column title is "How.comfortable.would.you.be.seeing.someone.who.practices.a.different.religion.from.you..Ask.you.about.your.religion..unprompted..in.conversation" and each response is one of the responses plotted on the graph, however some did not have a response which I why I'm trying to make the "no response" variable on the plot but it's not working.

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput()` instead of sharing a picture with us? We can't recreate your plot without the data

Comment: You need to include the line `library(ggplot2)` in your reprex so that it loads the package and will solve all those `could not find function "ggplot"` errors. And the other packages you're using too, `dplyr`, `forcats`, maybe more...

Comment: @cbear23 please run `dput()` and copy and paste the output into your question. We can't do anything if you just add `dput()` to the question we need the output

Comment: Okay, I made the edit.

Comment: These links may be useful: [Using reprex](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) and  [advice on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?)